# Reledmac : customise the position of footnotes

Tags: reledmac

If it's possible, I would like to customise the position of critical and familiar footnotes in order to have the following layout in my apparatus :

- One serie of familiar footnotes (\footnoteA)
- The critical footnotes (\Afootnote, \Bfootnote ...)
- The other series of familiar footnotes (\footnoteB, \footnoteC ...)

Is there a way to make that ?

Regards,

Comment: I was anxious when people would ask for this. For now, it is not possible. Please open a github issue, it should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

The version 2.16.0 of reledmac, just send on CTAN, provides tools to customize the order.

The `\fnpos` command can have a syntax which defines customize order. 
For your need, add the following code in your preamble:

```
\fnpos{%
  {A}{familiar},
  {A}{critical},%
  {B}{critical},%
  {C}{critical},%
  {D}{critical},%
  {E}{critical},%
  {B}{familiar},%
  {C}{familiar},%
  {D}{familiar},%
  {E}{familiar}%
}
```

Note that with this option, you must define explicitly all the position of the footnote.